# ngIf does not observe variable change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

The following is an HTML code snippets where ngIf checks for `forceAngle` to be true, by default `forceAngle` is false. Once the button is clicked I call the `ForceAngles()` function and set `forceAngle` to true. The issue is once it is set to true, ngIf should check the status and show the correct template. At the moment I don't get the changes as expected. I'm new to this domain and surfed for hours on the internet to get a proper solution. I think I missed an Angular fundamental. Need expert support on this.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="AssemblyAngle">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]='txt-wrapper'> Assembly Angles</mat-header-cell>
            <div *ngIf="forceAngle == 'true' ; else inputtemplate;">
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <span class="txt-inner">{{forceAngle}}</span>
              </mat-cell>
            </div>
            <ng-template #inputtemplate>

              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="txt-wrapper mat-header-cell">
               abc
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-template>
      </ng-container>

<button class="btn-secondary" (click)="ForceAngles()">Force Angles</button>
```

.ts file

```
ForceAngles() {
  this.forceAngle = 'true';
  
  this.loadCompressorOptimizeData();
  console.log(this.forceAngle);
  return this.forceAngle;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that nothing triggers Angular **change detection** mechanism. You have two ways to solve it:

#### First one

Implement mechanism which will trigger change detection using `tick()` method from `ApplicationRef` class:

```
import {ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

export class Component {
  constructor(private ref: ApplicationRef) {}

  ForceAngles() {
     this.forceAngle = 'true';

     this.loadCompressorOptimizeData();
     console.log(this.forceAngle);
     this.ref.tick();
     return this.forceAngle;
  }
}
```

Take a look at this answer for more information: [Trigger update of component view from service - No Provider for ChangeDetectorRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511820/trigger-update-of-component-view-from-service-no-provider-for-changedetectorre/40075680#40075680)

#### Another one

Use `observable` as `forceAngle` type, and `async` pipe in your template (`async` pipe triggers change detection automatically when a new value is pushed to observable).

Example .ts:

```
export class Component {
    forceAngle: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    someMethod(): void {
        this.forceAngle.next(true);
    }
}
```

and template:

```
<div *ngIf="(forceAngle | async) == true">some div</div>
```

Here you can find a nice article about change detection in Angular:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: The first work fine for me. I have seen in most of the article but I couldn't get it work out.